# How to append current version to post URL - versioning a post

Tags: cache, routes, csrf, entry-versions

I'm middle of a PWA app and one of the problems facing is versioning, once the post cached using Service Worker and if any change amended(ex: if it is an event post, the event end date may be extended.) to the post still user sees the old post.

```
https://sample.com/event/this-will-happen-after-covid?v=12042020
```

If I can add 'Date Updated' as a parameter of the URL I hope I can manage with. If there better approach, much appreciated.

The second question about `csrf token` please check the example.

```
        let api = '/actions/favourite/get-favourite-ids';

        let data = {
            'id': {{ currentUser.id }}
        };

        data['{{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName }}'] = '{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken }}';


        $.ajax({
            url: api,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {

                addFavoriteIcon(result)

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            },beforeSend: function(){

            },
            complete: function(){


            }
        });
```

I realised that due to `csrf token` is also cached, 400 error produced.

What are the better approach get rid of these two issues?